# How to turn the absolute numbers in a Stacked Bar Chart to relative numbers (in Neo4J Chart)?

Tags: graph, charts, neo4j, output, cypher

This code

```
MATCH q = (r:Representative)-[f:FACILITATED]->(b)
WHERE NOT b:VuurpijlMatch
RETURN DISTINCT f.year AS index,
    b.type AS key,
    count(*) AS value
ORDER BY index ASC
```

gives me this graph in return. Since Neo4J's Chart shows a poor format, I therefore added manually the numbers at the X-as. I circled the absolute numbers as an example in the first bar.

[Graph with absolute numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frGxM.png)

What I am looking for is a way to change the output from absolute numbers to relative numbers. See next graph as example of what I mean.

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nITX.png)

Anyone who can help me plotting the relative values, thanks a lot!

Comment: To calculate relative values, there should be a benchmark or a upper limit, what is it?

Comment: The absolute value / upper limit is the sum of the absolute values per bar on the X-as. So for the first bar, the sum = 229 + 668 = 897. The relative values in the first bar (with a total of 100%) should thus be 229 / 897 = 25.5% and 668 / 897 = 74.5%. Since Charts uses b.type to immediatele separate count(*) in the two values 226 and 897, I do not know how to get the total value to make from 226 and 897 relative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate relative values, you need the total count per year, along with the counts per label type. To do this we will need two aggregation ops, one to calculate the total count per year and another one to get the count per label per year. Then we can calculate the relative values, after filtering out the unnecessary rows. Something like this:

```
MATCH q = (r:Representative)-[f:FACILITATED]->(b)
WHERE NOT b:VuurpijlMatch
WITH DISTINCT f.year AS index, count(*) AS totalCountPerYear
MATCH q = (r:Representative)-[f:FACILITATED]->(b)
WHERE NOT b:VuurpijlMatch
WITH DISTINCT f.year AS year, index, totalCountPerYear, b.type AS key, count(*) AS typeValue
WITH index, key, round((typeValue * 100.0 / totalCountPerYear)) AS value WHERE index = year
RETURN index, key, value
ORDER BY index ASC
```

Comment: I think you are very close :) I do get results, only the values are all 0.0
But it does give a percentage (albeit 0.0) for each of the six index / key results.

Comment: Cheers Charchit! You're a hero!

Comment: Happy to help man, improves my knowledge, solves your problem. :)